# How to encode on client `transaction.transactionReceipt` with base64?

Tags: ios, objective-c, skpaymenttransaction

I am trying to validate IAP and to send to my server receipt which I then send to apple server to validate, I am using sandbox account and I get all the time status 21002 ( receipt missing or malformed ). I have in Objective C code

```
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction
```

object and I am sending

`transaction.transactionReceipt`

to my server and then pack and pass to apple server. How to encode on client

`transaction.transactionReceipt`
 with base64 ?

Do I need to encode with base64 on client `transaction.transactionReceipt` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since iOS7 there is another way to get the receipt data. Here is what I do:

```
NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];

NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptUrl];

NSString *receiptBase64 = [receiptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Then you send receiptBase64 to your server :)